# Changing the default taxonomy key length

Tags: taxonomy

I want to change the taxonomy key length to support keys greater than 32 chars.  I have adopted a custom WooCommerce store where some WP core files **wp-includes/taxonomy.php** have been edited to change `if ( strlen( $taxonomy ) > 32 )` to `if ( strlen( $taxonomy ) > 255 )`.  Is there a way I can abstract this away from the core files but still allow for the key length to be greater than 32?

Comment: Your problem is database. I assume that you edited the length of `taxonomy` column in `wp_term_taxonomy` table, but what happen if an update on db schema will revert that changes? You can edit again the length after that, but in meanwhile your taxonomy names will be truncated... Once names are not labels (so that long names can't be related to *display* issue), I guess you are using taxonomy names for something that goes beyond *normal* usage... Are you sure there is no another alternative?

Comment: I didn't do it, but I need to work with it.  There are hundreds of rows in the table containing keys with a length of 34 and 36.  I was hoping for a hook or filter that might help before I tackle refactoring the code to work within the original taxonomy limit.